# Does iPhone have a clipboard API?

Tags: ios, clipboard, pasteboard

Does iPhone have a clipboard API?  It seems one can call an API function to set text to the pasteboard which will be accessible by other apps., but can someone verify that this is correct?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, see [UIPasteboard Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html)

Answer (score 4):

yes, search for UIPasteboard.  Only available in OS 3.0 and later, of course.